# WAS Console Broken java.io.FileNotFoundException: /secure/layouts/ApplicationServer.collection.table.extends

Tags: java, configuration, websphere

On clicking on Servers->Application Servers link on WAS 6 console, I got the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /secure/layouts/ApplicationServer.collection.table.extends
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:424)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:639)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1042)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:137)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:177)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:756)
    at org.apache.struts.taglib.tiles.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag
```

It was working fine the other day.

Can anyone please suggest the reason for this?

Comment: We created new profile, but facing the same problem with the new profile as well! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that the ISC (Admin console) is somehow corrupted.

Try and restore this using iscdeploy -restore.

I have always used this if i suspect that the admin console is somehow not working as expected.

Find below a link to a blog comment which talks briefly about this and it has a reference to an IBM doc (which is for Process Server but the content is appropriate for WAS too).

http://blog.danzrobok.com/2008/10/06/websphere-admin-console-404-filenotfound-errors-when-clicking-certain-hyperlinks/

HTH

Manglu

Answer (score 0):

Someone probably really deleted files he should not have deleted or the file access rights are broken.

Comment: I want to understand what file could have been deleted (though it is lowest probability) and get it rectified. Thanks in anticipation.